# How to find the first transaction done by customers?

Tags: sql, sas

In a consumer spend data, how can I find the first transaction done by customers. For example, if you have 50 transactions, and you have 10 different customers who have done these 50 transactions, then how can I find the first transaction done by each of these 10 customers?
Suggestions to do this in SAS or SQL would really help.

Comment: If you have transaction date with column, it is possible. Post the table structure

Comment: Try looking into `by` groups and `first.` processing in a data step.  This is very basic SAS programming, which can easily be solved by searching on the internet.  When asking a question on this forum, you should show what research or attempts you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Here You need first transaction of each customer thats why here i use `RANK()` function and partition records acc to the customer_id, this function will return value 1,for first transaction of each customer so i use `firsttransaction=1` in `where` clause and we can not use `RANK()` func in `where` clause directly so here i use INLINE concept for applying condition on `RANK()` function

```
 Select * from ( Select customer, RANK() OVER(partition by customer_id Order by transaction_date) firsttransaction From table_name ) Where firsttransaction=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering in SQL.

If you are transaction date then use

```
Select min(transactiondate) from [Your Transaction table]
group by customer.
```

OR you can use directly

```
Select min(transaction) from [Your Table]
group by Customer.
```

Using group by will distinguish you each customer and `Min()` will find min or first transaction date of your each customer. You can add other criteria in a where clause to filter you result set. Like this

```
Select min(transaction) from [You Table]
where date>=[Starting transaction date] 
and date<=[End transactiondate].
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you need first transaction of each customer thats why i use RANK function and partition records acc to the customer_id. This function will return value 1 for the first transaction of each customer so i use firsttransaction=1 in where clause and we can not use RANK func in where clause directly so here i use INLINE concept for applying condition on RANK function

```
Select * from
          (
    Select customer,
    RANK()
    OVER(partition by customer_id
               Order by transaction_date) firsttransaction
    From table_name
            )
    Where firsttransaction=1
```